# Is it possibile in css to link a background image based on a link that appears in the HTML of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, background-image

The page html has a link in it, that I want to use as the background image of the page. The problem is that there are hundreds pages all with different links in them and I want to use this stylesheet to affect them all. Possible?

Comment: Please elaborate further. Do you mean you want the same background image on all pages based on some arbitrary url? Or do you have a url on each page you want to use? Is it just based on the first page you are visiting? (This is quite possible, just need to know your exact use case.)

Comment: Basically, I want a different background image on each page, and the image is sourced from a url that is present on each page.

Comment: Are you using Jquery?

Comment: Just to be extra clear, the page already displays the image in a div, I just want to use that image as the page background.

Comment: It's not my website, I'm just making a custom stylesheet for it, but I believe that they are using jquery

Comment: Stylesheets cannot get dynamic information from the DOM.

Comment: So it would be impossible to do within the css file?

Comment: That is correct. Externally included CSS stylesheets have no way of getting information from any inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Externally included CSS stylesheets have no way of getting information from any inputs or the DOM.**

Here is a basic solution using jquery.

Assuming jquery and a selector on the element that contains the URL.

IE:

```
 <img src="path/to/image.jpg" id="backgroundImage"/>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('load', function() {
    var imgSrc = $('#backgroundImage').prop('src');
    $(body).css('background', 'url(' + img + ')');
});
```

Comment: I don't know if I quite understand, doesn't this mean I have to have a link to the image? If not, what do I put in the "path/to/image.jpg"?

Comment: It means you can do what you need using javascript/jquery, but not using a css stylesheet.

Comment: And yes, the path/to/image.jpg would the the url/link you're referring to.

Comment: So if I made a javascript file, and then linked it in the css, I should be able to do it?

Comment: You would have to link it in the html page (or whatever type of page it is, php, asp, etc), not the css file.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate, I don't have access to that. Oh well.